# React native expo router v2 how to authentication flow?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I making a project using --template tabs@49 as base, and now it has this stucture:

-src
-app
-(auth)
-_layout
-index
-(tabs)
-_layout
-index
-two
-_layout
-context

my app layout look like this....
[app/_layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxmdU.png)
and its "working"
I mean when the context do change from AuthStack to TabsStack, but app stay on (auth)/index
Do I have to manually redicrect to (tabs)/index?

i tried to make a blank project e start over, but it keeps just like redirecting me to the first index file of the structure

Comment: Yes, you probably need to redirect to `(tabs)/index`

Answer (score 0):

I think that in expo router you should really avoid to conditionally render routing.

The root layout should export default a stack with app and auth routes.
Then you can try to conditionally return a redirect inside index based on authentication.

Or you can also try to place a hook inside the layout and do the redirect using router, to be honest I went with a hook but I started to think that it should be avoided and the navigation folder restructured a bit and nest a further app folder as suggested in latest expo documentation.